# How to insert whole function in TEXT segment?

Tags: linux, assembly, code-injection, ptrace

I need to insert a whole function code to TEXT segment with ptrace. I dont wont to overwrite some others byte in TEXT, but to insert a new function on free address space. Is it possible? maybe with PTRACE_POKETEXT or any other ways?